# Next JS React-Query API call with useQuery() works on the client but the equivalent API call doesn't work in getServerSideProps on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, react-query

I am trying to fetch data from the backend server using React Query in Next JS `getServerSideProps`. Here is the function to get the data:

```
export const getGoogleAuthUrl = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EXTERNAL_API_URL}/get-url`)
  return await res.json();
}
```

Here is my `getServerSideProps` code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery('getGoogleAuthUrl', getGoogleAuthUrl);

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { 
    props: { 
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient)
    } 
  }
}
```

In my console, I get the following error:
`FetchError: invalid json response body at http://backend-server/api/get-url reason: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4`

If I try to log the `dehydratedState` in the client by passing it as a prop, I get nothing in the state array like this:

```
{mutations: Array(0), queries: Array(0)}
```

Now if I make the same API call with `useQuery` on the client side, I get the correct response with no error. Here is how I call it on the client:

```
export default function GetUrl({ dehydratedState }) {
  // The dehydrated state from the getServerSideProps being logged as empty because it 
  // encounters an error and returns nothing
  console.log(dehydratedState);

  // API call with react-query useQuery method

  const {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data
  } = useQuery('googleAuthUrl', getGoogleAuthUrl);


  if(isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  if(error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
  if(data) console.log(data); //Logs correct data to the console

  return (
    <>
      Get Url from server
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably something to do with the way the API you are trying to access is configured.

Most likely, they are blocking traffic with suspicious user-agent strings, or perhaps with non-residential IP addresses. A lot of third-party APIs do this to prevent system abuse. Google in particular is quite strict with this.

I'd either try spoofing a user-agent string to see if you can work around it, or accept it as data that needs to be loaded client-side because of the API's security restrictions.

Comment: it would also be a good idea to look at the raw response - apparently, its not json parsable, so it would be nice to see what the api returns when called on the server side, as well as maybe see the status code. That could give a good hint.